# errors during booting process

Tags: raspbian, kernel

I just bought a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with NOOBS microSD Card.
I only connected the USB cable for power and the HDMI cable, it keeps rebooting with these errors, like it is stuck in a loop.

```
/init: line 27: can't create /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger: nonexistent directory
[     1.629060] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = w10: May 27 2016 00:13.30 version 7.45.41.26 (r640327) FWID 01-df77e4a7
[     1.656696] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg0021_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code
```

If I plug a "microsoft all in one media keyboard" it goes in kernel panic.

Comment: Watch the red power led closely while booting or plugging in the keyboard.  Does it flicker at all?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. One day, I normally shut down my Pi but on the next day I tried to turn it on and the screen went black, and it did not turn on and showed the same error message. I was scared that my SD card got corrupted, but finally, I could resolve the problem:

When the Pi tried to boot, it displayed `Hold Shift for Recovery Mode` for some seconds. I did so, and then I could edit the config file on the installation screen. It contained a line `device_tree=`, that I commented out, and then saved and pressed Exit.
Then my Pi rebooted and fortunately, it worked again.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your SD card might not have the correct installation or it might be corrupted.

Could you try reformatting your SD card and reinstalling NOOBS?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding boot_delay=3 to config.txt.  Causes a 3 second delay in the boot process.  Presumably, the SD card need time to start up.